# Can I add/remove the inputs one by one? - dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

Can I add/remove the inputs one by one?
The input should only post the currently selected array of files.

I am using [`dropzone.js`](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) for my current project and `dropzone.js` does not help to append file as HTML file input and how I can post image files when post data.

This is my script:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#filedrag",{
  url: "upload", // Set the Upload Url
  parallelUploads: 5,
  thumbnailWidth: 600,
  thumbnailHeight: 600,
  acceptedFiles:"image/*",
  previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
  maxFiles: 20,
  previewsContainer: "#previews",
  clickable: ".fileinput-button",
  init: function() {this.on("success", function(file, response) {
  });
  this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
  });
  }
});
```